# unable to launch application using deeplink url in detox for the IOS application

Tags: detox

**Unable to launch application using deeplink for the ios app in detox**

Initially the landing page in non react-native, after clicking on the link will be entering into the react-native page.

Tried with the

> await device.relaunchApp({url: url});

But this is not launching the deeplink url page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576538/detox-does-not-handle-universal-links)

You need update AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url
                            options:options];
}
```

and then in tests:

```
await device.openURL({url: 'url://someUrl',
                     sourceApp: 'some.app.id'});
```